# How do I fix this Pyspark which modifies a complex struct inside an array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

#### Problem Setup

Given a data frame where each row is a struct with an `answers` field that holds an array of answer structs, each with multiple fields, the following code is supposed to process each answer in the array, by examining its `render` field and applying some process to it. (Note this code is for an AWS Glue notebook running Glue 3.0, but aside from the spark context creation it should work on any PySpark >= 3.1):

```
%glue_version 3.0

import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

test_schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('question_id', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('subject', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('answers', T.ArrayType(
        T.StructType([
            T.StructField('render', T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField('encoding', T.StringType(), True),
            T.StructField('misc_info', T.StructType([
                T.StructField('test', T.StringType(), True)
            ]), True)
        ]), True), True)
    ])

json_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
    [1, "maths", [("[tex]a1[/tex]", "text", ("x",)),("a2", "text", ("y",))]],
    [2, "bio", [("b1", "text", ("z",)),("<p>b2</p>", "text", ("q",))]],
    [3, "physics", None]
], schema=test_schema)
json_df.show(truncate=False)
json_df.printSchema()
```

resulting in:

```
+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------------+
|question_id|subject|answers                                      |
+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------------+
|1          |maths  |[{[tex]a1[/tex], text, {x}}, {a2, text, {y}}]|
|2          |bio    |[{b1, text, {z}}, {<p>b2</p>, text, {q}}]    |
|3          |physics|null                                         |
+-----------+-------+---------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- question_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- answers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- render: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- encoding: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- misc_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```

Then taking the text processing method:

```
import re

@F.udf(returnType=T.StringType())
def determine_encoding_udf(render):
    if render:
        if "[tex]" in render:
            return "tex"
        
        match = re.search(r"<[^>]*>", render)
        if match:
            return "html"
    else:
        return "null render"
        
    return "text"
```

Apply the transformation:

```
def normalize_answer(answer):
    return answer.withField(
        "processed_render_input",
        answer.getField("render")
    ).withField(
        "encoding",
        determine_encoding_udf(answer.getField("render"))
    )

json_mod_df = json_df.withColumn(
    "answers", 
    F.transform("answers", normalize_answer)
)

json_mod_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Resulting in:

```
+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|question_id|subject|answers                                                                       |
+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1          |maths  |[{[tex]a1[/tex], null render, {x}, [tex]a1[/tex]}, {a2, null render, {y}, a2}]|
|2          |bio    |[{b1, null render, {z}, b1}, {<p>b2</p>, null render, {q}, <p>b2</p>}]        |
|3          |physics|null                                                                          |
+-----------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`process_text` is complex so this entire process can't be expressed in a lambda where the transform is defined.

#### The Problem

The problem is that when I run this on a much larger answers data set, `processed_text_input` is completely different text to the `encoding` field, i.e. what's in `encoding` seems to come from processing a completely different answer struct, from a different array from some other item in the input data frame. Sometimes it's also missing all together. In this toy example the text just seems to be missing, resulting in "null render" appearing in the encoding column for all examples. I tried adding 100 rows but in all cases the text was missing. I'm not sure why in my full version of this code with ~50k rows I get text from random rows. At any rate no text as shown in this toy problem isn't what I want either. The value in `processed_text_input` is the correct value from the corresponding answers text field.

Is this a bug or should I be structuring this expression differently? I know that I could explode the answers array and process it more traditionally, but I'm trying to use the more recent `transform` and `withField` functions.

#### Makeshift Solution

This isn't an answer per se, but it gets a solution so I'm posting it for anyone having the same problem. For a post to be awarded as the solution it would need to show how to achieve the result I want using transformations, this uses the explode function but it covers a non-trivial data structure. I've added this solution as an answer below, for those who like me skip straight to the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It will help if you can share more info like sample dataset.

I tried to recreate your problem; but `udf` call inside the lambda function for `array -> transform` results in some invalid state where probably the function  arguments are gone after evaluation. I wonder, how come your code is running fine.

Anyways, there is an alternative if you can explode the `answers` array and apply transformations on individual `answer` struct. This way you get benefit of Spark's distributed processing, too.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

json_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[[("txt1",),("txt2",),("txt3",)]]], schema="answers array<struct<text string>>")
json_df.show(truncate=False)
json_df.printSchema()

@F.udf(returnType=T.StringType())
def process_text(text):
    return "foo: " + text

def normalize_answer(answer):
    return answer.withField(
        "processed_text",
        process_text(answer.getField("text"))
    ).withField(
        "processed_text_input",
        answer.getField("text")
    )

json_df = json_df.withColumn("answers", F.explode("answers"))

json_df = json_df.withColumn("processed_text", F.col("answers").getField("text"))
json_df = json_df.withColumn("processed_text_input", process_text(F.col("answers").getField("text")))

json_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Sample dataset used is array with 3 text literals:

```
+------------------------+
|answers                 |
+------------------------+
|[{txt1}, {txt2}, {txt3}]|
+------------------------+

root
 |-- answers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------------+--------------------+
|answers|processed_text|processed_text_input|
+-------+--------------+--------------------+
|{txt1} |txt1          |foo: txt1           |
|{txt2} |txt2          |foo: txt2           |
|{txt3} |txt3          |foo: txt3           |
+-------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've updated the question with a toy example. The text passed to the UDF just seems to be missing, is this what you meant by the invalid state? On my full version with ~50k rows I start getting text from other rows. How can I fix the UDF so it gets the answer data? If not, how would I take your exploded code and then reverse it to the original structure? I know in the toy example I could group by answer_id then agg and collect_list on answers, but in reality I have dozens of fields at the answer_id level and selecting all of these from the group by looks ugly. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a case of using UDF inside a transformation (or aggregation) function. Not sure, if this is supported. I searched for problems with similar context; but most of them solve by moving all logic either in lambda of `transform()` or `withColumn()` with a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in the question, I have a makeshift solution. This is related to Azhar's answer where they suggest using the explode function, but ultimately I was looking for an answer that uses transformations and already had a sense of solving this problem using the explode function. So here's a full answer using the explode function, which processes the non-trivial data structure in the question, modifying the encoding value for each answer based on the corresponding render field, then collapses the data back into it's original structure:

```
json_mod_df = json_df.withColumn(
    "answers", 
    F.explode_outer("answers")
).withColumn(
    "answers",
    F.col("answers").withField(
        "encoding",
        determine_encoding_udf(
            F.col("answers").getField("render")
        )
    )
).groupBy(
    "question_id", "subject"
).agg(
    F.collect_list("answers").alias("answers")
)

json_mod_df.show(truncate=False)
json_df.printSchema()
```

Resulting in:

```
+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
|question_id|subject|answers                                     |
+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
|2          |bio    |[{b1, text, {z}}, {<p>b2</p>, html, {q}}]   |
|1          |maths  |[{[tex]a1[/tex], tex, {x}}, {a2, text, {y}}]|
|3          |physics|[]                                          |
+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- question_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- answers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- render: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- encoding: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- misc_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```

Note that in my full requirements beyond the scope of this question, I also needed to modify field's within the misc_info struct, for the above example, this can be achieved with:

```
.withColumn(
    "answers",
    F.col("answers").withField(
        "misc_info.test",
        F.col("answers").getField("misc_info").getField("test")
    )
)
```

In my actual code I'm doing the following:

```
.withColumn(
    "answers",
    F.col("answers").withField(
        "misc_info.comments",
        F.coalesce(F.col("answers").getField("misc_info").getField("comments"), F.array())
    )
)
```